# OnInitializedAsync method is not called

Tags: blazor

I browse to abc.razor OnInitializedAsync() method gets called.

now in OnvalidSubmit method I have the following code

```
  NavManager.NavigateTo("/abc?rid=1", false, true);
```

which means it should navigate to abc.razor page again. It does navigate but doesnot call the
OnInitializedAsync() method?

why so?

Comment: Why do this at all?  You are already on the page, no need to reload it.

Comment: I am setting this extra parameter rid=1 and i want other child controls also accessible to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you navigate to self, i.e. to the same page, the Router component passes the same route component into `RouteView` in `App`.

The Renderer sees no component change so treats the event as a re-render.  `OnInitialized{Async}` is not run.

`OnParametersSet{Async}` is run and the `Rid` parameter will be updated.  So use `OnParametersSet{Async}` for your logic.

Here's my Demo Page:

```cs
@page "/Reload"
<h3>Reload</h3>
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
<div class="alert alert-info">
    @this.Rid
</div>

<div class="alert alert-primary">
    @this.value
</div>

<BasicComponent RID=@this.Rid />

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.ReloadComponent>Reload</button>
</div>
@code {
    private string value = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public string? Rid { get; set; }

    private void ReloadComponent()
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo($"/Reload?Rid={DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        value = $"Reloaded at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }
}
```

And BasicComponent.razor:

```cs
<h3>BasicComponent</h3>

<div class="alert alert-dark">
    @RID
</div>

<div class="alert alert-secondary">
    @this.value
</div>

@code {
    private string value = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string RID { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        value = $"Reloaded at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    }
}
```

#### For Reference

The relevant code in `ComponentBase` looks like this.  `_initialized` is already true.

```cs
    public virtual Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            _initialized = true;

            return RunInitAndSetParametersAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return CallOnParametersSetAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have misread my answer, so I've updated it.  What I've shown you is the relevant private code in  `ComponentBase` as an explanation of why the behaviour is happening.

Comment: See my updated answer with demo code.

Comment: on the same note if the reload page has another child component, will the OnParametersSet() of the child component be called as well?

Comment: Yes, if you're using it in the component logic.  It's only being re-rendered because the renderer detects a parameter change when rendering the route component.

Comment: See my updated answer for a working example with a sub-component.